# Forma correcta de escribir un bucle que se repita mientras una condición se cumpla: ¿es realmente DO-WHILE?

Tags: bucles, lenguaje-agnóstico

[image: imagen del quiz]

> *Forma correcta de escribir un bucle que se repita mientras una condición se cumpla:
>
> FOR
>
> FOREACH
>
> DO
>
> DO WHILE*

Estaba en un quiz (estoy haciendo un curso de programación). Yo puse la respuesta "FOR-ROJO" pero el profesor dice que es "DO WHILE-VERDE". Sigo pensando en que yo estoy en que la verdadera era `WHILE` pero no estaba y que la que más se acerca es el `FOR`. En el quiz no pude tener explicación del porqué.

¿Por qué es `Do While`?

Comment: ¿Sabés la diferencia entre `WHILE` y `DO-WHILE`?

Comment: se que el whilo lo hace mientras se cumpla la condicion, y el do while lo hace una vez si no se cumple.

Answer (score 0):

`for`, `while`, `foreach`, etc son estructuras de control cuyas palabras claves son comunes en muchos lenguajes, pero esto no quiere decir que para todos los lenguajes sea lo mismo, por esto creo que la base de esta pregunta está mal planteada, no es posible responder si no se dice el lenguaje

Así que para ser consecuente, voy a responder en terminos de `javascript` por que el sitio permite ejecutar este lenguaje directamente, es el lenguaje más usado y tiene similitudes de su sintaxis con muchos otros lenguajes

El `DO` a seca no me suena para nada, así que lo descarto. El `foreach` funciona contra iteradores no contra condiciones, así que también lo descarto

El `while` y el `do while` son muy parecidos, ambos funcionan con condiciones, solo que el primero evalúa la condición primero y el segundo evalua la condición al final, lo que provoca que el `do while` siempre ejecute lo que está en su cuerpo al menos una vez.

Entonces cualquiera `while` o `do while` es una respuesta correcta

Por último está el `for`, el cual tiene diferentes formas, la más habitual (pero no la unica) es `for ([expresion-inicial]; [condicion]; [expresion-final])` donde el segundo argumento es una condición de parada. Por lo que para mi, tecnicamente, tu respuesta es correcta. Además cada argumento de un `for` es opcional, entonces perfectamente puede operar igual que un `while`

Por ejemplo

Por ejemplo:
Un bucle mientras `i` sea menor a 5

Con **while**

```js
let i=0;
while(i < 5){
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Con un **For**

```js
let i=0;
for(;i<5;){
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Con lo cual queda demostrado que el `while` y el `for` pueden llegar a ser equivalentes segun como se escriba el `for`, por lo que para mi tambien es correcta la respuesta.

---

Nota: Evidentemente el último código se escribe mejor como:

```js
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```